# How to call Events and Method Using VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, events, logging, listbox

I have One Vb.net application. Which contain a list box.

And I want to add the Message in this List Box from another class Using Events.

Basically I am trying to create Status Logger So I can log Steps and show into List box.

Comment: And what have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Maybe start looking at how events work and how to make your own events?

Answer (score 3):

Create a new class which has an event defined

```
Public Class EventTest
    Public Event StatusChanged(ByVal status As String)

    Private _status As String = ""

    Public Property Status As String
        Get
            Return _status
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _status = value
            'raise the status changed event when the status property is changed
            RaiseEvent StatusChanged(value)
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Now, create an instance of this class in your form (note the `withevents` keyword):

```
Dim WithEvents Foo As New EventTest

'Handle the status change event
Private Sub Foo_StatusChanged(status As String) Handles Foo.StatusChanged
    lstStatus.items.add(status)
End Sub
```

Now change the status and see it appear in the listbox:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Foo.Status = "Initialised"
End Sub
```